# How can I install a 1.6.4 mod and a 1.7.2 mod with Forge?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Ouch. That hurt :(

Time: 10/02/14 9:09 AM
Description: There was a severe problem during mod loading that has caused the game to fail

cpw.mods.fml.common.LoaderException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.toomuchtnt.TooMuchTNT
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.transition(LoadController.java:163)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:497)
    at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:194)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:495)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:849)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:134)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.toomuchtnt.TooMuchTNT
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.ModClassLoader.loadClass(ModClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:443)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:314)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:296)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:267)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:209)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:314)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:296)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:267)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:119)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:487)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:180)
    ... 38 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.2
    Operating System: Windows 7 (x86) version 6.1
    Java Version: 1.7.0_45, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode, sharing), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 36777328 bytes (35 MB) / 143261696 bytes (136 MB) up to 518979584 bytes (494 MB)
    JVM Flags: 2 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx512M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP v9.01-pre FML v7.2.109.1019 Minecraft Forge 10.12.0.1019 5 mods loaded, 5 mods active
    mcp{8.09} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    FML{7.2.109.1019} [Forge Mod Loader] (forge-1.7.2-10.12.0.1019.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    Forge{10.12.0.1019} [Minecraft Forge] (forge-1.7.2-10.12.0.1019.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    TooManyItems{1.7.2} [TooManyItems] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    TooMuchTNT{2.6} [TooMuchTNT] (TooMuchTNT v2.6) Unloaded->Errored
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can't get a 1.6.4 & a 1.7.2 mod working at the same time.

Comment: @shanodin That sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get a 1.6.4 and a 1.7.2 mod working at the same time, especially with Forge. Because of the huge changes between the 1.6.x and the 1.7.x versions of Minecraft, there is almost no inter-compatibility between mods.